# Store object in asmx to session and get this value in master page - get null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, session

I try to store my object to session in a asmx web service

```
 user = new MyUser(UserName);
 Session["user"] = user;
```

and read from a master page in page load section but I get null

```
user = (MyUser)Session["user"];
```

it work when I try with a simple string instead of `MyUser` object

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: is your `MyUser` serializable?

Comment: yes it is: '[Serializable] public class User'

Comment: if you're sure that it works with string, then I have no clue, for me, the logical part is not to work at all and they **will** probably have 2 different pools and `Sessions`'s are not shared like that. I would use SQL Sessions or a Cache system to change messages between.

Comment: And when I try to get this object in the asmx page I can, but from another page I can't ...

Comment: ..I will not prefer putting session variables in webservices..though did you tried it like this : HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user?

Comment: yes I've tried HttpContext.Current.Session
Strange, because when I try get value from aspx file it work, but from the mester page not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
In the master page I tried to read session on the `Page_Load` event, but it was wrong. 
When I put in `Page_Init` event it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the process running your service is the same serving up your pages, you need to ensure the WebMethod has the session enabled by decorating the method with

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Here is another answer with [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758575/how-acess-session-in-webmethod).

Comment: Thanks, but I already use this, and the session is work, but when I try to read an object from the session in the master page, get null

Comment: @Jaime Torres Ohhhh man, this is not a "simple answer"... this one saves me a complete rollback of few days of work until I got stuck on an issue where this single attribute solves it... Thanks man. Like your name meaning in french; «`J'aime` vraiment ta réponse!» (I really like your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Who's the client of the service and who is the client of the page? Are they sharing cookies?

Answers to these questions are fundamental because session sharing involves sharing a session cookie with the same session id.

From what you write it is not clear but most probably you just have to share (for example **copy**) cookies between two clients - the web service client and the page client.

Comment: What is "the same client". A web browser? A desktop application?