# Unable to save and get value from web service session ASMX asp.net on AJAX Call

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, session, asmx

Need help on setting and getting object from session in asp.net web services. I am saving session in one method of service and when try to retrieve it , just gives null. Sample code is bellow for saving session

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string setObj(NameValue[] formVars)
    {
       MyObject obj = new MyObject();
       obj.vlaue = "1";
       Session["obj"] = (object) obj;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("");
     }
```

For getting session :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getObj(NameValue[] formVars)
    {
       MyObject obj = new MyObject();

        obj = (MyObject)Session["obj"] ;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj.value);
     }
```

In above code session data is null. I have also add session state in web config but won't work:

```
<system.web>

 <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly.. use HttpContext.Current.Session.. Also why are you casting your Myobject down to an object when you store it in session? Just store it as MyObject.

Comment: @Wheels73 I have used HttpContext.Current.Session but this won't work either. also tried by direct storing Myobject in session. Still gives Null on next method call..:(

Comment: have you checked the sessionid on the Session object when setting and retrieving...are they the same?

Comment: nope they are also different..

Comment: Try remove the web config entry for session altogether. The default is in process anyway. You may be overriding the default, then missing a config entry... Sure this happened to me in a project.

Comment: @Wheels73 still not working for me..

Comment: Ok.. well not sure I can remember the last time I used session in a web method... here are some SO answers that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758575/how-can-i-access-session-in-a-webmethod.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571800/why-can-webmethod-access-session-state-without-enablesessionstate/15711748#15711748. cheers

Comment: How did you test it ? It seems to work.

Comment: @jstreet i am calling this service from ajax.

Comment: @Wheels73 thanks man for response . Let see what i can find in this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am saving session in one method of service and when try to retrieve it , just gives null.

If these 2 methods are during the same request, it will be null. a session variable in .Net is set on the client side in the response headers, but when you try to read them they are from the client's request headers, which have not changed since the request was made.