# Cannot get Session state in Web Service from ajax on client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, session

I would like to have only 1 session for each user. But the system generate new one session when I run ajax query.
There were no problems when I tested it on debug mode on my computer. Problems rised only in  client site on distributed application.

ASP page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btn_ASP" runat="server" onclick="btn_ASP_Click" Text="Asp" />
<input id="btn_JS" type="button" value="JS" onclick="GetUsersList();" /><br />
```

Asp button which generates 'ConnectCount' Session element:

```
protected void btn_ASP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] == null)
        count = 1;
    else
        count = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] + 1;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] = count;
    TextBox1.Text = count.ToString();          
}
```

Web Service code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public string Get_UsersList2()
{
    int count;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] == null)
        count = 1;
    else
        count = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] + 1;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] = count;
    return count.ToString();
}
```

Ajax query to Web Service

```
function GetUsersList() {            
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WbSrv_ACTR.asmx/Get_UsersList2',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{}',
        success: function (data, st) {
            if (st == "success") {
                if (data.d != "") {
                    text1.value = data.d;
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Cannot get list of users");
        }
    });
}
```

Code in buttons just adds 1 to Session["ConnectCount"].

So when I click 5 times on Asp button and 1 time on JQ button (on local IIS - testing):

```
result: asp = 5, jq = 6 (correct)
```

do the same operations on server IIS 7.5:

```
result: asp = 5, jq = 1 (incorrect)
```

Server uses other session.
For testing - I've added some elements in Session via ASP button and couldn't find them in Web Service (Session was empty there but **SessionID was the same**)

**Could anyone have solution or workaround?**

Web config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong way of using session in web service

```
Session["ConnectCount"];
```

The right way is

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"];
```

So your function should be

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string Get_UsersList2()
    {
        int count;
        if ( HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] == null)
            count = 1;
        else
            count = (int) HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] + 1;
         HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectCount"] = count;
        return count.ToString();
    }
```

Reference

[How can I access session in a webmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758575/how-can-i-access-session-in-a-webmethod)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've changed the code as you suggested. but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. When I run ajax query - system gets Session with the same ID as in APS button but it doesn't have any elements - the session is empty. But in debug mode all works fine - I can add parameter in Session from asp button and  read it from Web Service.