# How can I keep all html in session with webservice?

Tags: jquery, web-services

I want to keep that full html in my page in session using with webservice but
set session step throw this exception.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My functions are

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Gsetsession")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public void SetSession(string html)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["html"] = html;
}

[WebMethod(Description = "GetSession")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public string GetSession()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["html"] != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["html"].ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access session in a webmethod?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758575/how-can-i-access-session-in-a-webmethod)

Answer (score 0):

In your web methods, make sure you enable session

```
[ WebMethod(Description="Get Session",EnableSession=true)]
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)