# How to clear a specific session when user left the page

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I  have a page. There are some session variables those are used in a specified page only. How to clear those session variables when user left the page.

When user left the page using the menu/URL.

I have tried with

```
 protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Rules"] = null;
        Session.Remove("Rules");
    }
```

But it is now working :(

Please suggest.

Comment: if you want to use the storage for particular page then use `ViewState`  but not  `Session` : Session data is only useful for storing data beyond the lifetime of a page. If you don't want to store it beyond the life of a page then Session data is not for you here.

Comment: @Webruster, I fear if ViewState can slow down the page

Comment: how much data you gonna store in `Session["Rules"]` ?

Comment: What if the user closes his browser? You can't react on a clientside action at serverside. If the user clicks a hyperlink he will also be redirected immediately. The only workaround i can think of is using an invisible iframe(0 pixel size) and handle it's `onbeforeunload` event. There you could [use a `WebMethod`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4760165/284240) to clear the session.

But it's not worth the effort in my opinion. Either don't use the session for this purpose or let it expire.